# How to uninstall SmartSVN on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, uninstall, smartsvn

I cannot find any information on how to cleanly uninstall SmartSVN on Ubuntu. I'm not using it at the moment and part of the reason is that on the latest Ubuntu upgrade it has somehow hijacked some of the Nautilus functions and opens some directories and attached drives with SmartSVN.

The official documentation has nothing on this. Simply removing the program directory may have unintended issues that I would like to avoid, namely the Unity hooks on opening directories.

It was installed using the shell script from the official page at http://www.smartsvn.com/download.

Answer (score 1):

In the `tar.gz` file that they supply, there are scripts for creating/removing the launcher shortcuts. I ran the `remove-menuitem.sh` which seemed to do the job.

SmartSVN has stopped opening when I want to access a removable drive.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command: `gio mime MIMETYPE [Handler]` to get or set the handler for specific mimetype.
For directory use the following to set it for Nautilus:
`gio mime inode/directory org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop`